# Unable to open port 443, despite apache listening, ufw open locally on machine

Tags: networking, apache2, iptables, firewall

Hello fellow ubuntu lovers.
I've been trying to open port 443 on my server (on a private network) for some time, but I'm stuck. It's open on ufw, and apache is listening to that port, but somehow I cannot access that port from a different machine on the same private network (both are on the same router)

Here I listed the output from the usual port troubleshooting commands. Would highly appreciate any help you can give me, thank you! :)

NOTE: I am running Ubuntu 13.04 (i know it's old, but I have a project that does not allow me to upgrade).

result of wget from within the server 192.168.0.11 443 (it's clearly connecting)

wget https://192.168.0.11 --no-check-certificate

```
Connecting to 192.168.0.11:443... connected.
WARNING: cannot verify 192.168.0.11's certificate, issued by ‘/C=AT/O=ZeroSSL/CN=ZeroSSL RSA Domain Secure Site CA’:
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
result of wget from machine on the same private network (clearly not connecting)
```

wget https://192.168.0.11 --no-check-certificate

```
Connecting to 192.168.0.11:443... failed: Operation timed out.
Retrying.
```

Result of nmap -sT 192.168.0.11 from within the server (IP of server). Clearly open.

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.11
Host is up (0.00050s latency).
Not shown: 993 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
443/tcp  open  https
1723/tcp open  pptp
8009/tcp open  ajp13
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
8081/tcp open  blackice-icecap

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.07 seconds
```

Result of nmap -sT 192.168.0.11 (from a client on the same private network) - port looks closed

```
Starting Nmap 7.91 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-12-16 09:10 EST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.11
Host is up (0.0021s latency).
Not shown: 997 filtered ports
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp  open   ssh
80/tcp  open   http
444/tcp closed snpp

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 4.16 seconds
```

result of netstat -tlnp (looks like apache is bound and listening)

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1232/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8081            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1207/mono       
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2074/dnsmasq    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      993/sshd        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1061/cupsd      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1723            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1248/pptpd      
tcp6       0      0 :::8009                 :::*                    LISTEN      1370/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      27146/apache2   
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      1370/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      993/sshd        
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      1061/cupsd      
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      27146/apache2   
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN      1370/java
Result of sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -P (looks like apache is listening)

COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd      993     root    3u  IPv4    8811      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd      993     root    4u  IPv6    8813      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
cupsd    1061     root    9u  IPv6 1121403      0t0  TCP ip6-localhost:631 (LISTEN)
cupsd    1061     root   10u  IPv4 1121404      0t0  TCP localhost:631 (LISTEN)
mono     1207 dekiwiki    5u  IPv4   10961      0t0  TCP *:8081 (LISTEN)
mysqld   1232    mysql   10u  IPv4   12403      0t0  TCP localhost:3306 (LISTEN)
pptpd    1248     root    6u  IPv4   10654      0t0  TCP *:1723 (LISTEN)
java     1370   tomcat   48u  IPv6   11175      0t0  TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
java     1370   tomcat   53u  IPv6   11179      0t0  TCP *:8009 (LISTEN)
java     1370   tomcat   72u  IPv6   14691      0t0  TCP localhost:8005 (LISTEN)
dnsmasq  2074   nobody    5u  IPv4   12631      0t0  TCP aperture:53 (LISTEN)
apache2 27146     root    4u  IPv6 1141498      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2 27146     root    6u  IPv6 1141502      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2 27151 www-data    4u  IPv6 1141498      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2 27151 www-data    6u  IPv6 1141502      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2 27152 www-data    4u  IPv6 1141498      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2 27152 www-data    6u  IPv6 1141502      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2 27153 www-data    4u  IPv6 1141498      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2 27153 www-data    6u  IPv6 1141502      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2 27154 www-data    4u  IPv6 1141498      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2 27154 www-data    6u  IPv6 1141502      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2 27155 www-data    4u  IPv6 1141498      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2 27155 www-data    6u  IPv6 1141502      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2 27158 www-data    4u  IPv6 1141498      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2 27158 www-data    6u  IPv6 1141502      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
```

Result of ufw status:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
444/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
444/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

result of sudo iptables -L It's a big output, so I put it in pastebin
(I tried sudo iptables -I INPUT 5 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT)

https://pastebin.com/DV8A3EFF

Comment: Apache appears to only be listening for IPV6 connections, but you are trying to connect via IPV4.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Linux machines typically hide a dualstack IPv4+IPv6 socket behind listening on IPv6 address ::    Having said that I tried 0.0.0.0:443 and it still same problem.

Comment: ufw log? Apache log? Wireshark?

Answer (score 0):

For those who are struggling with the same problem, I changed apache to port 8443, and forwarded all 443 traffic to 8443.  I still don't know why port 443 is blocked.  It works now.

When I switched apache to 8443, the 8443 port became open on nmap -P.  However when I switched back to 443, the 443 port did not open.  So clearly there is something stopping 443 from being opened.

It is possible it has to do with my Tp-Link Archer AX-60 router.  Not sure, why 443 traffic within the private network is being blocked.

Comment: How (specfically) did you forward all 443 traffic to 8443 ?